# ICLRRuntimeInfo into my dll - possible?

Tags: c#

I have a mixed mode 2.0 dll, and a 4.0 dll. I want to supply this

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup> 
</configuration>
```

to my dll. Without an app.config (or changing machine.config) is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot supply this information just for single assembly - the entire application will be executed either on top of 2.0 or 4.0 runtime host.

If the question is how to support v2.0 and v4.0 in application without app.config - see [Embedding supportedRuntime into exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270489/embedding-supportedruntime-into-exe-file/45056961)